# Changing the Acessibility of files in java in order to avoid Security Errors

Tags: java, intellij-idea, error-handling, runtimeexception, access-denied

I am trying to overwrite some basic textfiles using the class Files and I am struggling to do so since my program throws a couple of Access Denied Security Errors, which makes testing my program quite difficult, so I wanted to ask whether there was a possibility to change the Accessibility of files in Java in order to avoid these kinds of Errors.
(The IDE I am using is IntelliJ)
the files are basic editor text files

Comment: On which operating system is the application executed? Can the user which runs intellij delete the files?

Comment: yes that is possible